# Printing an empty ggplot with a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to print an empty ggplot, but still include a legend/scale and I'm running into problems.

Here's the relevant section of the code:

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(year_id), y=location_name)) + 

  geom_point(aes(size=count.sum), na.rm=F) +
  #geom_blank() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=50, hjust=1)) +
  labs(x="Year", y="") +
  scale_size(name="Site-years of data", range=c(min(breaks),max(breaks)), breaks=breaks) + 
  ggtitle(paste0(cause_name, ", Data Availability")) +
  facet_wrap(~type) 

plots[[i]] <- p
```

Breaks is just the vector 1,2 and the column count.sum is all NA.
What I want is to print out the chart, which has no data in it (no points), but still have a legend with a small dot representing 1 and a bigger dot representing 2.

As it is right now, I get the error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

If I use geom_blank instead of geom_point, the chart successfully gets created and is empty, but there's no legend,

How can I get both the empty chart and a legend?

Thanks

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hard to tell without an example, but some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131173/getting-legend-coloring-in-an-empty-ggplot) that involve removing aesthetics to make the points invisible.  If you set the point color to NA and then use `override.aes` to add it to the legend you might get close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you could zoom somewhere outside the range of the data, `ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10), aes(x,x,size=x)) + geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(20,30))`